# How can I delete Google+ Activity Log without deleting posts/actions?

Tags: google-plus

Today I found out that Google keeps a log of my activities, like posts, comments, +1's, etc.

It can be found at https://plus.google.com/apps/activities/posts

This web page has an option to delete posts, comments or undo +1's, but I could not find options to delete the logs without deleting posts / actions.

This activity log is different from the logs at https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols , which can be stopped and cleared.

In my country the government can prosecute a person if he +1'd a wrong video or picture.

How do I clear the former Activity Log without deleting posts/actions?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, **You Can't**. The activity log is part of googles services and you can't stop the fact it logs your actions. Indeed it's not only Google. Every major social network platform and even most websites log your actions.
The only major protection you have is that these logs are held by the parent Google company in US servers, which are subject to a warrant upheld by a US court. **Most US courts will not give a warrant** to a foreign government unless substantial evidence to prove the individual is engaging in terrorism is proved.

If you are engaging in legitimate politically subversive activity in your home country. There are some steps you can take to protect yourself.

- Use a proxy server or VPN e.g [Betternet](https://www.betternet.co/)
- Use a proxy network (Basically more layers of proxy servers) e.g [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en)
- IF your engaged in whistle-blowing use an encrypted file share service e.g. [SecureDrop](https://securedrop.org/)
- Use an SSL or similar encrypted service when communicating with other people

None of these will work if your government is a member of the [Five-Eyes Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes). In which case you're out of luck.